# Fillable Form with Calculated Total of Non-Blank Lines in Table

Tags: hyperref, forms, javascript

folks. I'm trying to create a form that sums up how many names there are in a user-filled table. Essentially, find all the non-blank cells (with a certain variable name), and add 1 to the sum each time, then output that sum to a read-only form-fillable hyperref field. What's the best way to execute this?

I was able to figure out how to do basic summation calculations for integers, but haven't figured out how to sum up non-blank cells yet.

Code below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=0.25in, right=0.25in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eforms}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}


\newcommand{\no}{\textnumero}

\newcommand{\dimrule}{\color{light-gray}\hrule}

\newcommand{\blank}[2]{
    \textField[\BG{0.95 0.95 0.95}\W{0}\Q{1}]{#1}{#2}{1em}
}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        
        \begin{center}
            
            \textbf{\large{}List}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                & Name\\
                1. & \blank{listName1}{30ex}\\
                2. & \blank{listName2}{30ex}\\
                3. & \blank{listName3}{30ex}\\
                4. & \blank{listName4}{30ex}\\
                5. & \blank{listName5}{30ex}\\
                6. & \blank{listName6}{30ex}\\
                7. & \blank{listName7}{30ex}\\
                8. & \blank{listName8}{30ex}\\
                9. & \blank{listName9}{30ex}\\
                10. & \blank{listName10}{30ex}\\
            \end{tabular}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                Total Records Printed: & \TextField[
                calculate={
                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                },
                width=20ex,
                readonly=true,
                backgroundcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95},
                bordercolor=
                ]{}\\
            \end{tabular}
        
        \end{center}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The calculation that simply has "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" is where I have tried and failed with a number of different attempts.

Comment: If it's related to Latex, please Edit your question and post the code. Please keep relevant parts, drop unimportant ones, still showing your point, ready for copy & compile.

Comment: Updated, thanks.

Comment: That's better. // Can you please name or describe briefly your fruitless attempts? Here a code snippet might be fine, as it's in context now, if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you stick to either the `hyperref` package or to the `eforms` package and don't combine them. Since the `hyperref` package has also other uses, I would recommend using it. In the following, I will give solutions for either choice.

Apart from that, I removed some packages and defintions from your code that are not essential to these examples.

---

To use the `hyperref` package, you need to redefine your `\blank` macro a bit. Note that in order to refer to a `\TextField` via JavaScript, you need to give it a `name`. You also need to name the field that does the calculation.

The script that does the calculation loops over the fields named `listName1` to `listName10` and checks for each whether the value of this field is not empty. If yes, it adds 1 to the variable `result` which is finally entered into the field named `totalRecords`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.25in, right=0.25in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{eforms}

\newcommand{\blank}[2]{
    \TextField[backgroundcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95},bordercolor={},width=#2,name=#1]{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        
        \begin{center}
            
            \textbf{\large{}List}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                & Name\\
                1. & \blank{listName1}{30ex}\\
                2. & \blank{listName2}{30ex}\\
                3. & \blank{listName3}{30ex}\\
                4. & \blank{listName4}{30ex}\\
                5. & \blank{listName5}{30ex}\\
                6. & \blank{listName6}{30ex}\\
                7. & \blank{listName7}{30ex}\\
                8. & \blank{listName8}{30ex}\\
                9. & \blank{listName9}{30ex}\\
                10. & \blank{listName10}{30ex}\\
            \end{tabular}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                Total Records Printed: & \TextField[
                name=totalRecords,
                calculate={
                    var result = 0;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        if (this.getField('listName' + i).value != '') {
                            result++;
                        }
                    }
                    event.value = result;
                },
                width=20ex,
                readonly=true,
                backgroundcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95},
                bordercolor={},
                default=0
                ]{}\\
            \end{tabular}
        
        \end{center}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

---

In case you want to stick to the `eforms` package, you can do as follows (the script that does the calculation is the same as above):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.25in, right=0.25in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{eforms}

\newcommand{\blank}[2]{
    \textField[\BG{0.95 0.95 0.95}\W{0}\Q{0}]{#1}{#2}{1em}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        
        \begin{center}
            
            \textbf{\large{}List}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                & Name\\
                1. & \blank{listName1}{30ex}\\
                2. & \blank{listName2}{30ex}\\
                3. & \blank{listName3}{30ex}\\
                4. & \blank{listName4}{30ex}\\
                5. & \blank{listName5}{30ex}\\
                6. & \blank{listName6}{30ex}\\
                7. & \blank{listName7}{30ex}\\
                8. & \blank{listName8}{30ex}\\
                9. & \blank{listName9}{30ex}\\
                10. & \blank{listName10}{30ex}\\
            \end{tabular}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                Total Records Printed: & \textField[
                \BG{0.95 0.95 0.95}\W{0}\Q{0}\V{0}\Ff{\FfReadOnly}
                \AA{\AACalculate{
                    var result = 0;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        if (this.getField('listName' + i).value != '') {
                            result++;
                        }
                    }
                    event.value = result;
                }}
                ]{totalRecords}{20ex}{1em}\\
            \end{tabular}
        
        \end{center}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

And finally, there is also a more user friendly way to use the `eforms` package using the option `useui`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.25in, right=0.25in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[useui]{eforms}

\newcommand{\blank}[2]{
    \textField[\ui{bgcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95},border={invisible},align={left}}]{#1}{#2}{1em}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        
        \begin{center}
            
            \textbf{\large{}List}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                & Name\\
                1. & \blank{listName1}{30ex}\\
                2. & \blank{listName2}{30ex}\\
                3. & \blank{listName3}{30ex}\\
                4. & \blank{listName4}{30ex}\\
                5. & \blank{listName5}{30ex}\\
                6. & \blank{listName6}{30ex}\\
                7. & \blank{listName7}{30ex}\\
                8. & \blank{listName8}{30ex}\\
                9. & \blank{listName9}{30ex}\\
                10. & \blank{listName10}{30ex}\\
            \end{tabular}
            
            \bigskip
            
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                Total Records Printed: & \textField[\ui{
                bgcolor={0.95 0.95 0.95},border={invisible},align={left},value={0},fieldflags={readonly},
                calculate={
                    var result = 0;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        if (this.getField('listName' + i).value != '') {
                            result++;
                        }
                    }
                    event.value = result;
                }
                }]{totalRecords}{20ex}{1em}\\
            \end{tabular}
        
        \end{center}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

---

Either approach will result in the following output:

[image]

Comment: This worked out wonderfully, thank you very kindly!

Comment: Do you know how to execute this with checkboxes? I tried applying this to checkboxes as well, but the only result in the total is 10 (with the code snippet unaltered) or 0 (with value == "Yes").

Comment: The important thing would be that your checkboxes are also named. But then, `this.getField('listName' + i).value == 'Yes'` (or whatever you named the boxes) should work. In case that this does not work, consider asking a new question on this site.